# why the translated kotlin code complains about a Array<BaseData>? to be a Array<out BaseData>

Tags: kotlin, kotlin-generics

Having a java class,  using androidStudio to translate to kotlin.
Got a error and not sure how to correctly translate it.

The java code:

```
public class BaseDataImpl extends BaseData {

    private final BaseData[] translators;

    public BaseDataImpl(final BaseData... translators) {
        this.translators = cloneArray(translators);
    }

    public static <T> T[] cloneArray(final T[] array) {
        if (array == null) {
            return null;
        }
        return array.clone();
    }

}
```

after the code translation, got error: `required Array<BaseData>?, found Array<out BaseData>`,  but the `translators`  in the `cloneArray<BaseData>(translators)` call is defined as  `val translators: Array<BaseData>?`,

anyone could help to explain?

```
class BaseDataImpl(vararg translators: BaseData) : BaseData() {

    private val translators: Array<BaseData>?

    init {
        this.translators = cloneArray<BaseData>(translators)  //<=== error:  required Array<BaseData>?, found Array<out BaseData>
    }

    companion object {
        fun <T> cloneArray(array: Array<T>?): Array<T>? {
            return array?.clone()
        }
    }

}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is written in the [Kotlin function reference regarding varargs](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/functions.html#variable-number-of-arguments-varargs):

> Inside a function a vararg-parameter of type `T` is visible as an array of `T`, i.e. the `ts` variable in the example above has type `Array<out T>`.

where the referenced function was:

```
function <T> asList(vararg ts: T): List<T>
```

So in your case you actually pass an `Array<out BaseData>` but you only accept an array of type `Array<T>?` (in your case `Array<BaseData>`). Either you adapt all of the types to `Array<out T>` (which basically is similar as saying `List<? extends BaseData>` in Java) or you take care that you are only dealing with `T`s instead, e.g. with:

```
inline fun <reified T> cloneArray(array: Array<out T>?): Array<T>? {
        return array?.clone()?.map { it }?.toTypedArray()
}
```

But look up the documentation regarding this: [Kotlin generics reference - type projections](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/generics.html#type-projections). You probably can accomplish this even easier.